# Stop Jquery.ajax from adding [] to the variable name of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a function like below, it sends to an api, but returns an error because it isnt receiving the test parameter, when I look through the network tab it shows that the actual parameter name being sent is `test[]` is there away to not have ajax rename my variable to `test[]` so that i can access said api?

```
  var data = {
      "test":[1,2,3]
  }
  $.ajax({
    url : 'API/url',
    type : 'POST',
    data : data,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(){do stuff}
  });
```

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(data)` would turn the input into json.  But your backend would also have to expect the input to be json as well and parse it for usage.

Comment: @Taplar ya thats the issue, i cant mess with the backend, I tried using the `traditional` param which kinda solved the issue but it turns everything into an string so types are not preserved so its not ideal.